# Issue with horizontal left aligned form

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make a second form beneath my first. The issue is that I can't seem to move the second form down. I've tried padding and margin in my css. I did it in the .label2 #input2 and the other fields that affect my second form. I can't seem to include attributes in my css for #form2. I tried adding multiple attributes in my #form2 css but none of it is similar. I referenced it the exact same way as my #form1 (which works) so I am unsure why my padding-top in #form2 does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

* {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

body {
 background-image: url(/img/bamboo.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-color:black;
 text-align:center;
}

#container {
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:0px;
 width:920px;
 height:920px;
 text-align:left;
 background-color:00000;
}

.twoCol {
 height:55em;
 margin:2%;
 width:46%;
 background-color:0000;
 float:left;
}

#logo {
 margin:0px;
 float:left;
}

#whatis {
 font-family: rockwell;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:1.4em;
 padding-top:2em;
 color:#cccccc;
}

#about {
 font-family: rockwell;
 letter-spacing:.1em;
 line-height:1.3em;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:1.1em;
 padding-top:.2em;
 color:#ffff99;
}

#equal {
 padding-top:1em;
 padding-left: 9em;
}

#signup {
 font-family:rockwell;
 float:left;
 font-size:1.5em;
 padding-top:2em;
 padding-bottom:100px;
 color:#339900;
}

#form1 {
 padding-top:6em;
 width:450px;
}

#form2 {
 width:450px;
}

#formleft {
 float:left;
}

#formright {
 float:right;
}

.label {
display:block;
margin-left:1em;
margin-bottom:-.3em;
font-size:.85em;
color:white;
font-family: Avenir;
text-shadow: px px px white;
}

.label2 {
 margin-top:13px;
 display:block;
 margin-left:0em;
 margin-bottom:0em;
 font-size:1em;
 color:white;
 font-family: Avenir;
 text-shadow: px px px white;
}

input {
 font-family: Courier New;
 font-size: 1em;
 height:1.4em;
 margin:2% 5% 5% 5%;
 width:90%;
 border-color:#555555;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}

#input2 {
 font-family: Courier New;
 font-size: 1em;
 height:1.4em;
 margin:-4% 0% 0% 15%;
 width:75%;
 border-color:#555555;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}

.inset {
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}

button {
 height:2em;
 margin:0% 5% 5% 5%;
 width:92%;
 background-color:#00aeff;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border-color:#008aff;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px grey;
}

button:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}

.submit input2{
 margin-left: 1em;
}


text{
 font-family: Avenir;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">

    <div id="left" class="twoCol">

    <div id="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png" height= "150px" width="257px" alt="">

    <div id="whatis">
      <p>What is Epic Swap?</p></div>

    <div id="about">
      <p>Epic Swap is the opportunity to share<br> an  experience, make a friend and do<br> it all over again.</p></div>

    <div id="equal">
      <img src="/img/equal.png" height="56" width="100" alt=""></div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="right" class="twoCol">
        <form id="form1">
       <div id="formleft"><label class="label">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" /></div>
       <div id="formright"><label class="label">Password:</label>
          <input type="text" /></div>
        <div id="signup">
          <p>Sign Up Now!!</p></div>

        <form id="form2">
           <p><label class="label2" for="name">Name</label2> 
           <input id="input2" type="text" id="name" /></p>

           <p><label class="label2" for="e-mail">E-mail</label2>
           <input id="input2" type="text" id="e-mail" /></p>
           <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
       </form>
    </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/BpgMn/ second form seems to be beneath the first one. what's wrong there?

Comment: the "name"label is stuck up top and not aligning with the input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistakes in you code:**

1. `#form1` tag is opened and but it is not closed anywhere
2. `<label>` tag has wrong closing that is `</label2>`
3. tag closing is not in proper

Check the [modified code](http://jsbin.com/uhunuc/1/edit) and see the [result](http://jsbin.com/uhunuc/1)

Comment: Huge thanks. I went through that same stuff multiple eyes and didn't catch my messups. Thanks again!!

Comment: the other thing is that I cant seem to get the label aligned horizontally with the input. The label wants to be on top of the input. Vertical margin and padding controls don't seem to be helping me. I'm able to accomplish it with relative positioning. But I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clear: both` to your #form2 CSS.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The site is live at www.epicswap.com

Answer (score 0):

I need your HTML code, but my initial guess is your second form needs a (clear: left;)

Comment: my html is at the bottom of the css that i posted. It begins with <form id="form2"> thanks

Comment: your first form does not close..."</form>"

Comment: Good eye, I closed the <form> but it didn't make a difference as far as moving down form2. The name part is still stuck up top.

Comment: I cant seem to get the "name" moved down next to the input box. I can easily position form1 with padding-top, but that does not seem to work with form2.